# Get Contact Record from Account List

Tags: apex, soql, salesforce-id

Below is the query I am using in my code.

```
List<Account> accounts = [Select Id, 
                                 (Select Id,FirstName, LastName From Contacts), 
                                 Name, 
                                 BillingCountry 
                            from Account];
```

NOw I want to get Contact Record from this account List.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
List<Account> accounts = [Select Id,(Select Id,FirstName, LastName From Contacts), Name, BillingCountry from Account];

for(Account objAcc:accounts  )
{
    //iterate over contact. here objAcc.Contacts is list
    for(Contact objCon: objAcc.Contacts)
    {
       System.debug('---contact---'+objCon);
    }
}
```